# Access n-th dimension in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I want a easy to read access to some parts of a multidimensional numpy array. For any array accessing the first dimension is easy (`b[index]`). Accessing the sixth dimension on the other hand is "hard" (especially to read).

```
b[:,:,:,:,:,index] #the next person to read the code will have to count the :
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Especially is there a way, where the axis is not known while writing the program?

Edit:
The indexed dimension is not necessarily the last dimension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a view and want it fast you can just create the index manually:

```
arr[(slice(None), )*5 + (your_index, )]
#                   ^---- This is equivalent to 5 colons: `:, :, :, :, :`
```

Which is much faster than `np.take` and only marginally slower than indexing with `:`s:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.random((10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))

np.testing.assert_array_equal(arr[:,:,:,:,:,4], arr.take(4, axis=5))
np.testing.assert_array_equal(arr[:,:,:,:,:,4], arr[(slice(None), )*5 + (4, )])
%timeit arr.take(4, axis=5)
# 18.6 ms ± 249 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit arr[(slice(None), )*5 + (4, )]
# 2.72 µs ± 39.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit arr[:, :, :, :, :, 4]
# 2.29 µs ± 107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But maybe not as readable, so if you need that often you probably should put it in a function with a meaningful name:

```
def index_axis(arr, index, axis):
    return arr[(slice(None), )*axis + (index, )]

np.testing.assert_array_equal(arr[:,:,:,:,:,4], index_axis(arr, 4, axis=5))

%timeit index_axis(arr, 4, axis=5)
# 3.79 µs ± 127 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Interesting. Any idea why it would be faster than the official `np.take`?

Comment: @EricDuminil `np.take` makes a copy (slow) while normal indexing returns a view (quite fast).

Comment: Is it therefore correct, that your handmade version is only faster, when the `index` does not require a copy? I.e. index are consequtive numbers?

Comment: I haven't timed it. At least the difference will be much less. And what do you mean with consecutive numbers? There is just one?!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html).
For example:

```
b.take(index, axis=5)
```

Comment: Awesome. `np.arange(2**6).reshape((2,2,2,2,2,2)).take(1, axis=5)` The more I learn about numpy, the more I enjoy it.

Answer (score 5):

An intermediate way (in readability and time) between the answers of MSeifert and kazemakase is using [`np.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html#numpy.rollaxis):

```
np.rollaxis(b, axis=5)[index]
```

Testing the solutions:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.random((10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))

np.testing.assert_array_equal(arr[:,:,:,:,:,4], arr.take(4, axis=5))
np.testing.assert_array_equal(arr[:,:,:,:,:,4], arr[(slice(None), )*5 + (4, )])
np.testing.assert_array_equal(arr[:,:,:,:,:,4], np.rollaxis(arr, 5)[4])

%timeit arr.take(4, axis=5)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 4.44 ms per loop
%timeit arr[(slice(None), )*5 + (4, )]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 731 ns per loop
%timeit arr[:, :, :, :, :, 4]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 540 ns per loop
%timeit np.rollaxis(arr, 5)[4]
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.41 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of @Jürg Merlin Spaak's `rollaxis` but much faster and not [deprecated](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html):

```
b.swapaxes(0, axis)[index]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can say:

```
slice = b[..., index]
```

Comment: I guess this only works, when I want to index the last dimension, right?

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak Ah, yes, I thought you meant the last dimension in general. If you want something like the previous to last you could do `b[..., index, :]` or something like that, but then `np.take` would be clearer I guess.